# List rows that have an ID in common in the same table with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building an activities website and I want to show on user's profiles the common activities I'm going to with this other user.

So I have a table as follow :

[image]

Every time a user clicks "join" on an activity page, a new row is added to this table with :

- the user_id who joined
- the activity_id (event) attended

So on each user's profile, I want to list the different activities we have in common.

If the user's IDs are for example 1 and 10, then I can list the activities they go to with this query :

```
SELECT * FROM `activity_user` WHERE user_id IN(1, 10)
```

However, how to update this query to return only activities IDs they have in common?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple JOIN with the same table:

```
SELECT a1.activity_id
FROM activity_user a1
JOIN activity_user a2 ON a2.activity_id = a1.activity_id
WHERE a1.user_id = 1
  AND a2.user_id = 10
```

Another way is to `GROUP BY activity_id` and only return activities, which both users have, by counting the rows per group:

```
SELECT activity_id
FROM activity_user
WHERE user_id IN(1, 10)
GROUP BY activity_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of user is only limited to 2, this is quite simple using intersect clause -

```
SELECT activity_id
FROM `activity_user`
WHERE user_id = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT activity_id
FROM `activity_user`
WHERE user_id = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

For two users you can join two SELECT against same table on activity_id

```
SELECT a.activity_id
FROM test a
JOIN (SELECT activity_idFROM test WHERE user_id = 10) b ON a.activity_id = b.activity_id
WHERE a.user_id = 1
```